# how to resolve 64 bit address of remote xbee using Arduino xbee library

Tags: arduino, xbee, addressing

Does anyone know how to resolve the 64 bit address of a remote xbee (series 2) using the Xbee Arduino library (http://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino) ?

The getRemoteAddress() public function of class ZBTxRequest returns only the the 16 bit address.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the method getAddress64() documented [here](http://xbee-arduino.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/class_z_b_tx_request.html)

It will give you back a XBeeAddress64 object though.

if you need the address itself you need to concatenate it with the methods getLSB and getMSB like this .

```
tx.getRemoteAddress64().getLsb()
```

hope this was useful